# insert json to postgres python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Hi i want to request data from a api where the output is in a JSON format. I want to take the data from the API an insert it into a postgress database, but i get the following error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/text.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Boliga VALUES (%s)", [Json(data)])
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""[\n {\n  \"estateId\": 1735758,\n  \"address\": \"Dysseaasen 15A\",\n  \"zipCode\": 2600,\n  \"price\": 5603000,\n  \"soldDate\": \"2021-05-31T22:00:00.000Z\",\n  \"propertyType\": 1,\n  \"saleType\": \"Alm. Salg\",\n  \"sqmPrice\": 35018.75,\n  \"rooms\": 6.0,\n  \"size\": 160,\n  \"buildYear\": 2019,\n  \"change\": 2.9017446,\n  \"guid\": \"18C3917E-E80F-4FF1-BAAA-05DCFF36938C\",\n  \"latitude\": 55.683464,\n  \"longitude\": 12.424398,\n  \"municipalityCode\": 161,\n  \"estateCode\": 319,\n  \"city\": \"Glostrup\",\n  \"groupKey\": null,\n  \"canGetVR\": true\n },\n {\n  \"estateId\": 0,\n  \"address\": \"Skovbrynet 34\",\n  \"zipCode\": 9330,\n  \"price\": 1111111,\n  \"soldDate\": \"2021-05-28T22:00:00.000Z\",\n  \"propertyType\": 1,\n  \"saleType\": \"Alm. Salg\",\n  \"sqmPrice\": 7507.507,\n  \"rooms\": 5.0,\n  \"size\": 148,\n  \"buildYear\": 1977,\n  \"change\": 0.0,\n  \"guid\": \"94199131-1023-496C-89F4-0FA101D80269\",\n  \"latitude\": 57.160492,\n  \"longitude\": 10.28083,\n  \"municipalityCode\": 810,\n  \"estateCode\": 14258,\n  \"city\": \"Dronninglund\",\n  \"groupKey\": null,\n  \"canGetVR\": true\n }\n]""
```

I have the following python code

```py
import requests as r
import json
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from psycopg2.extras import Json
import pandas as pd


d=r.get('https://api.boliga.dk/api/v2/sold/search/results?pageSize=2').json()
data=json.dumps(d['results'], indent=1,ensure_ascii=False)
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_NAME = "bolig"
DB_USER = "postgres"
DB_PASS = "Password"
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST)
cur= con.cursor() 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Boliga VALUES (%s)", [Json(data)])
```

My table looks like this

```py
 estateid | address | zipcode | price | solddate | propertytype | saletype | sqmprice | rooms | size | buildyear | change | guid | latitude | longitude | municipalitycode | estatecode | city | groupkey | cangetvr 
----------+---------+---------+-------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-----------+--------+------+----------+-----------+------------------+------------+------+----------+----------
```

Comment: Are you copying some example for `from psycopg2.extras import Json` that you expected to work? Can you link to it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont re-stringify the request
2. Your response appears to be a list, not a single object that can be flattened into columns.

Consult [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation) you can see they call `Json()` around a standard Python dictionary, not a list and not a string.

So, try the following

```
d = r.get('https://api.boliga.dk/api/v2/sold/search/results?pageSize=2').json()

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST)
cur = con.cursor() 
for obj in d:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Boliga VALUES (%s)", [ Json(obj) ])

# be sure to commit/close the cursor
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to adjust the capitalization of some of your database fields to match the JSON response, or parse the response and fix the field names yourself

Comment: It doesn't work because what I want is in the d['results'] and when I added it to your code i get the same error.. but thanks for the try!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/text.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Boliga VALUES (%s)", [ Json(obj) ])
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: (...)
LINE 1: INSERT INTO Boliga VALUES ('{"estateId": 1735758, "address":...

Comment: If you want the results, then you can use `d = r.get(...).json()['results']`

Comment: Based on the single quote in `VALUES ('{`, I think you're still getting a stringified JSON object. Hard to say if that is because of the `%s`, though

Comment: Thank you for your guidnes OneCricketeer, how do i handle the stringified JSON object?

Comment: Simply dont use `json.dumps`